# Instantiating lists correctly

Tags: c#

Sorry if this is a bit of a silly question but I think I'm misunderstanding something basic about Lists and Goggling hasn't helped. This is what I have:

A class containing List elements:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public int Age { get; set; }
public List<int> Main_Spec { get; set; }
public List<int> Aux_Spec { get; set; }

public Department()
{
    List<int> Main_Spec = new List<int>();
    List<int> Aux_Spec = new List<int>();
}
```

I then try to add elements to Main_Spec as follows:

```
Department departnment = new Department();
List<int> inter = new List<int>();

var parts2 = parts[2].Split(',');
foreach (string part in parts2)
{
   inter.Add(int.Parse(part));
}
departnment.Main_Spec = inter;
inter.Clear();
```

I use the intermediate list because when I tried to add straight to department.Main_Spec I got an error saying that the object isn't instantiated (or something along those lines). My Problem is that looking at it in debugging mode, when I clear inter, department.Main_Spec also gets cleared. That's not what I'm trying to achieve and I don't really understand why it's doing that.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're declaring a local variable in constructor. Just drop `List<int>` and that should be fine.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't ever feel silly about asking silly questions. It's a great way to learn, and sometimes you even discover the answer while you're explaining the question!

Comment: inter and departnment are references to List<int>s, and saying departnment.Main_Spec = inter means these references are now equal. This assignment does not make a copy of the List<int> itself, it only sets the references equal. Whatever you do to the list inter references can also be seen through departnment.Main_Spec. If I tell you how to access a bank account with $1000 in it, then I withdraw all of the money, you can't get the $1000 any more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have a small mistake in your constructor. You should define the local properties of the class instead of trying to declare and define new ones (local to the constructor):

```
public Department()
{
    this.Main_Spec = new List<int>();
    this.Aux_Spec = new List<int>();
}
```

Now you can go back to the original way of not using an intermediate class. For example:

```
Department departnment = new Department();
department.Main_Spec.AddRange(parts[2].Split(',').Select(p => int.Parse(p));
```

Here I also avoided using the for-loop with `AddRange()`.

Comment: By the way, the Lists are `Properties` and not `Fields`

Comment: Yup, gotta reference the class members using the 'this' keyword. New instantiations within the constructor just creates variables local to the constructor function.

Comment: @Freestyle076: The `this` isn't necessary here, I just added it to illustrate that we're referencing the class's own properties.

Comment: Oh right, C# has implicit self-referencing too. Good catch @Cory!

Answer (score 3):

Change your constructor to this:

```
public Department()
{
    Main_Spec = new List<int>();
    Aux_Spec = new List<int>();
}
```

You were using local (function level) variables instead of referring to the class level variables.